# Weird Syntax with Func<T,Z> as parameter, why does it work?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

So I have been using this for a while, I stumbled on the syntax while messing with it. But I still don't know exactly WHY it works, can someone explain it to me? How is this being broken down?

```
public T LoadData(Func<Z, T> func, Z arg) where T: class
{
  T data = func(arg);

  return data;
}

public T LoadData(Func<Z, T> func) where T: class
{
  return LoadData<object, T>(arg => func(), null); // <--- Why does the arg => func() part work? It basically ignores the parameter when it gets passed in for some reason...
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
public IEnumerable<CategoryTypes> GetCategories()
{
  return LoadData(CategoryProvider.GetCategoriesByGroupId, 12);
}
```

OR

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetStatesLookup()
{
  return LoadData(StatesProvider.GetStates);
}
```

PS: This is pseudo code, the real reason I use this is a bit more involved than the example above...

Updated to fix my accidental reversal of the generics when I typed this up on here...
Update 2: Fixed accidentally defining arg a T instead of Z

Comment: You haven't even provided a full definition of the methods. What's T? What's Z? You're using a generic method but the definition of that generic method isn't even in your question.

Comment: Let this be pseudo code but post valid one. `T data = func(arg);` this won't compile. `Func<T,Z>` returns `Z` how can you assign it to `T` ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Also, the generic return type of the method needs to be Z.

Comment: @Asad Missed, Good that you pointed. looking through this code am wondering how this gets compiled :(

Comment: Sorry about the typos, I was typing this based off of memory since the computer I code on is isolated from the internet I had to type all of this from memory...

Comment: The definition of T and Z can by implicitly defined by their corresponding method signatures passed it via the method group. I don't have to explicitly define them, besides it not important. The question I had was how is the arg => func() satisfying the Func<Z, T> definition since it does not define a parameter...

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are creating a new lambda that satisfies `Func<T,Z>`

Answer (score 2):

It's wrapping the `Func<T, Z>` in another `Func<T, Z>`.  The only thing the new `Func<T, Z>` does is call the old `Func<T, Z>` **WITHOUT** considering `arg`.

You could swap out `arg => func()` with simply `func`, or `arg => func(arg)`

Comment: So I tried func, it doesn't work.  Does passing a null parameter into Func<Z, T> turn it into a Func<Z> ? Its not passing a null into the method group calls...

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  Doesn't compile?  Doesn't do waht you'd expect?  I don't even know what you expect to happen.  you're not showing what your methods are that are doing the actual work with the `Z` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The method `LoadData` is generic by `T` where `T` must be a `class`. However, the `T` is further passed in as the single parameter type for the `Func` that is passed to it. Finally, `Z` is used as the generic return type for the `Func`.

So in short, the `Func` that is passed in must receive the same type as what's defined when calling `LoadData`. It then returns a different type, which is of course defined when you send in the `Func` to `LoadData`.

So, this is why this works:

```
LoadData(CategoryProvider.GetCategoriesByGroupId, 12);
```

the `T` in this case is `int`, and the `Func` you passed in receives a single parameter that is of type `int`. What it returns, I don't know, but it doesn't matter - it's used as the `Z`.

That call may statically look something like this:

```
public int LoadData(Func<int, void> func, int arg)
```

To address the second set of pseudo code - I'm not convinced that even compiles nor am I convinced you have a real concrete example that's like that. You haven't satisfied the `T` and `void` would not be valid there. This is a perfect example of why pseudo code is not a good candidate for a question here.

Comment: The question was about why passing a lambda that invokes `func` without an argument works equivalently to the method above (it doesn't). You haven't addressed this in your answer.

Comment: @Asad, I'm not convinced the second set of pseudo code will compile. You haven't defined a `T` for the input type and `void` would not be valid there.

Comment: The first method in the pseudocode won't compile either, since there is a type mismatch in the value being assigned and the variable being assigned to.

Comment: @Asad, I don't disagree that the method itself wouldn't compile, but the call to the method in the first example would work.

Comment: @neoistheone The first example wouldn't work either because `void` isn't `int`.

Comment: @nmclean, `Z` is the return value of the function being passed in. Further, the static representation isn't real - it was just a way of breaking it down so it was more visible. The first parameter, `T`, is the input value.

Comment: @neoistheone Yes `T` is the input, but it must *also* be compatible with the output because the return value is actually assigned to a `T` variable (`T data = func(arg)`).

Comment: @nmclean, I believe the remainder of the community has fleshed out that the pseudo code inside the method is invalid and wouldn't compile. The question is in fact in question because it's not based on real, compilable code.

Comment: The generics were reversed in my pseudo code, sorry about that. But if you flip them then everything is how it should be, I edited the code above, it should be good now.

Comment: @emalamisura, well then that changes everything. However, it doesn't really change the explanation. It's just that `Z` and `T` are reversed at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be "translating" a function which takes no parameters into a function which takes one. The `null` in the second overload could be any value, because it is only passed into the function whose parameter is ignored.

However, the code as shown does not make sense. In the first overload, you have:

```
T data = func(arg);
```

Yet the return type of `func` is `Z`, not `T`. So this will only work if `Z` is a `T`.

Then in the second overload, `func` is called with no parameters, yet it is still a `Func<T,Z>`, meaning it must take a single `T` parameter.

It would make more sense if the type parameters were swapped (`Z` as the parameter type and `T` as the return type), and the second overload didn't use `Z`:

```
public T LoadData(Func<Z,T> func, Z arg) where T: class
{
  T data = func(arg);

  return data;
}

public T LoadData(Func<T> func) where T: class
{
  return LoadData<object, T>(arg => func(), null);
}
```